# How to increase the speed of a game by using a Timer?

Tags: c#, timer, onclick

I am doing a simple C# clicker game, I know it is stupid to ask, but I'm still learning C# and I am asking you pros how do you make the timer interval go faster every button click?

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int clicks = 0;
    private int counter = 1;

    public Form1()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UpdateButton()
    {
        if (clicks >= 50)
            button1.Enabled = true;
        else button1.Enabled = false;  
    }

    private void myDiamond_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {  
        myDiamond.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\\Matej Dodevski\\Semos\\C#\\Diamond Clicker\\diamond.png");  
    }

    private void myDiamond_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        myDiamond.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\\Matej Dodevski\\Semos\\C#\\Diamond  Clicker\\diamondMouseUp.png");
        clicks++;
        DiamondsScore.Text = "Diamonds: " + clicks.ToString();
        UpdateButton();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter++;

        clicks = clicks + 1;
        DiamondsScore.Text = "Diamonds: " + clicks.ToString();
        UpdateButton();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clicks = clicks - 50;
        DiamondsScore.Text = "Diamonds: " + clicks.ToString();
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        UpdateButton();
        button1.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: on your click event do **timer1.interval--;** NOTE. you will also have to check this interval doesn't go below 1!!!

Comment: if you open designer view, and press your timer. in the properties you should see 'Interval' (i think it's set to 250 as default). This property is the interval for your timer, and can be changed using the above code in your **Timer1_Tick** method

Comment: No, no, how can i stop going below 1 ?

Comment: what do you mean by *cost/clicks*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you will get a more natural feeling if you are decreasing the time interval by a constant factor.

Define the initial interval and the factor as doubles.

```
const double factor = 0.95;
double interval = 1000;
```

and at each click

```
interval *= factor; // Same as: interval = interval * factor;
timer1.Interval = (int)interval;
```

Comment: will this not 'jump' near the beginning of the timer1_Tick being fired, and then gradually slow? I.E. this will (on a time Vs Rate graph), appear as logarithmic?

Comment: Thanks a ton ! You guys helped me a lot! Continue with the great work :)

Comment: Yes, but I think that the player will feel this constant percentual change as an equaly increasing degree of difficulty. It gets 5 percent more difficult at each click. Logarithmic scales often appear more natural to our senses.

Comment: I was just thinking that it would get really hard really quickly! :P But is defo still a decent and 'different' approach to the task! :)

Comment: A constant change like `timer1.Interval--;` will first hardly be percievable (999 is almost the same as 1000). But near the end a change from 2 to 1 will cut the interval in half at a single click!

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes is that not game logic, though? :P Gets increasingly more difficult, faster? But back to the matter at hand, cost higher? Could you possibly clarify what you mean?

Comment: @jbutler483: I think that a perfect theory does not exist. You will have to make tests and make tweaks here and there until the game feels "right". Also the calculation of the score (clicks or whatever) should be fair. If the player gets a high score too early he will get bored. If its too hard to score he might get frustrated and abandon the game.

Comment: that's true, and I totally agree with there being no 'perfect' theory. It all depends on the game itself - who it's marketed at/ content of the game. But for this example, I think the OP (at present) just wants to have a 'working game'. We're getting off topic here :P

Answer (score 0):

Change the timer `Interval` property, see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval(v=vs.110).aspx)

you can for example do

```
timer1.Interval = timer1.Interval - TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10).TotalMilliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
    private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter++;

       if(timer1.Interval >1) //if the timer interval is bigger than one
       {
          timer1.Interval --;
       } 


       clicks = clicks + 1;
        DiamondsScore.Text = "Diamonds: " + clicks.ToString();
        UpdateButton();
    }
```

Note: The `timer1.Interval--;` is the same as `timer1.Interval = timer1.Interval - 1;`

This idea can be done with your `clicks` as well:

```
clicks++;
```